# Regex differentiate same string between brackets, braces, and parentheses

Tags: regex, parentheses, brackets

I have to differentiate between the following:

```
    [Secure] Rest of subject message
    (Secure) Another subject message
    {Secure}One without a space
```

Here's what I have from the old system:

```
    \[Secure\]
    \(Secure\)
    \{Secure\}
```

Problem is that my new vendor is adding brackets around the parentheses (out of my control) one so it's actually:

```
    [\(Secure\)]
```

So it triggers for both bracket and parentheses.

I can't figure out how to get the regex to end the string at the parentheses

Comment: Use negative lookarounds.

Comment: Maybe you can use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ndn0Po/1) `(?<=[\[\(\{])(?!\().+?(?=[\]\)\}])` with [positive and negative lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: I ended up using The following:

        (?<=[\(\{])(?!\()Secure+?(?=[\)\}])

I guess I learned from my first post that I should include absolutely everything relevant.  I had 3 separate policies... [secure] for encrypting email, and two for bouncing emails sent to (secure) and {secure}.  My old regex didn't work because [\(Secure\)] allowed parentheses and brackets.  For some reason [(?<=[\(\{])(?!\()Secure+?(?=[\)\}])] did not fail in my vendor's regex policy and it allowed everything to work.

Thank you, The fourth bird. I was able to mitigate a 2 hour email delay with your help.